# Theorems for Perpendicular and Parallel Vectors

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I know the following about lines:

If two lines are parallel to a third line, then they are parallel to each other.

If two lines are perpendicular to a third line, then they are parallel to each other.

But do the same theorems apply to vectors? I've tried relating the vector equation of the lines to their direction vectors in an attempt to understand, but I can't make the proper deductions. My intuition says no, because

<1, 0, 1> $\cdot$ <0, 1, 0> = 0 and <1, 0, 0> $\cdot$ <0, 1, 0> = 0, but there is no scalar c such that c<1, 0, 1> = <1, 0, 0>.

But I do know that a $\times$ b is perpendicular to a and b, and for some reason this implies that a $\times$ b is parallel to another vector that is perpendicular to a and b. Why is this so?

Edit: I should note I am referring only to vectors in 3D space.

Comment: Both of those statements hold for vectors as well as lines.  But note *where* they apply for lines (and thus vectors).  The first applies in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space for *any* $n$ while the second only applies in $2$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: If n and m are the normals to two planes, then the line of intersection is parallel to n×m. If the statement for perpendicular vectors does not hold in 3D space, how does this follow? I know that nxm is perpendicular to n and m, and for some reason is parallel to the line of intersection, which is also perpendicular to n and m.

Comment: $n$ and $m$ in this case *couldn't* be parallel to each other because then $n\times m=0$.  Look at [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#/media/File:Cross_product_vector.svg).  In it $a$, $b$, and $a\times b$ are all going in different directions -- that is, none of them are parallel to any of the others.

Comment: Space being $3$-dimensional literally *means* that there are three mutually perpendicular directions.  Consider this: the $x$-direction is perpendicular to the $z$-direction.  And the $y$-direction is perpendicular to the $z$-direction.  So by your theorem we might conclude that the $x$-direction is parallel to the $y$-direction.  But of course that's not true.  The $x$-direction is *also* perpendicular to the $y$-direction.  You can see that that theorem *does not hold* in $3$-dimensional space (or in fact any dimension $\ne 2$).